# Create a FacetGrid from barplot

Tags: python, bar-chart, facet-grid

How do I break this barplot apart to organise them by the day of the week?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oShlm.png

Here is my dataframe.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPOZ.png

**Barplot code:**

```
sleep_dow.plot(x="DayOfWeek", kind="bar", figsize=(8,6))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Try this: `sleep_dow.plot(x="DayOfWeek", kind="bar", subplots=True, figsize=(8,6))`

Comment: Hmm, it organised them by the total time in bed, total minutes asleep and awake time in bed instead of the day of the week.  Was thinking of keeping the 3 bars together but splitting them according to the days of week using a FacetGrid.